# $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}[f(x+1)-f(x)]=\alpha$ then $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Here is what I want to prove.

> If $f:(0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}[f(x+1)-f(x)]=\alpha$, show that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=\alpha$$

Here's what I've tried. I used the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit to convert the given statement to $|f(x+1)-f(x)| < \epsilon$ for large enough $x$, but I don't have any clue on how to proceed.

How do I manipulate this to get something of the form with $f(x)/x$ ?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**Note**. I've simplified the problem by setting $g(x) = f(x)-\alpha x$, so it is enough to show the problem only for $\alpha = 0$.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1041661/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1461048/42969